# Rewrite rules into web.config for js and png files

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an application ASP.Net, Web api with c# , that used https and I want the js, css files and images to be sent with http.
I try different thinks but it didn't work.
I've tried this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect Image to HTTP">
      <match url=".*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|js)$"/>  
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>

  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirect Image to HTTP">
      <match url=".*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|js)$"/>  
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found"/>

  </rules>
```

Comment: The same thing: the page is still loading , but the file that I tried to send by http are'n..

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should specify HTTPS as condition:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect Image to HTTP">
      <match url=".*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|js)$"/>  
      <conditions>
           <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="ON" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

BTW, it's better to use `.+` rather than `.*` in your regexp.

Comment: Maybe it's working, but the page still loading .. loading .. loading .. for about 3 minutes... The images that I tried to sent with http aren't loaded into page.

Comment: Did you try to load an image by direct link? What's the result?

Comment: I've tried now, and event if the image is with http or https the page doesn't stop from loading ... the images are'n loading.. What I have to do? What is wrong.. all this are on local machine.. aren't on server yet.

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. You have infinite redirect between http and https or 2. https wasn't configured correctly. Does everything work without this rule?

Comment: Yes .. the project work's fine without the rule... How can I check the infinite redirect? any suggestions? Thanks a lot

Comment: You can use developer tools to see what happens. I use Firebug for Firefox, Chrome has internal tools, other browser have such tools as well, as far as I know. Use "Network" tab so you can see something like that: https://getfirebug.com/network